# php strstr function not work in wordpress tag.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

i add following codes in WordPress theme tag.php file

```
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        $title = strstr(the_title(), '|', true);
        $link = get_permalink();
        echo '<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href="'.$link.'" target="_top" rel="noopener noreferrer">'.$title.'</a>';
    endwhile;
?>
```

it seems PHP strstr function not working in this file and $title not printed within a tag.
thanks in advance

Comment: trying `echo $link` lonely.

Comment: `the_title()` __outputs title__. To get title as string another function used. It is explained in the manual btw.

Comment: Provide an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You didnt provide all the required information to help you. Whats in `the_title()` (we dont want you to answer "obviously some title", we want an exact definition of what the value is)

Comment: thanks a lot u_mulder. the right function is  [get_the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) is a WordPress function. This question contains the `wordpress` tag, so we can assume that's what they're referencing.

Answer (score -1):

You sould replace the third argument of the_title() by false:

```
$title = strstr(the_title(), '|', true);
```

to

```
$title = strstr(the_title('','',false), '|', true);
```

> (void|string) Void if $echo argument is true, current post title if
> $echo is false.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/

Comment: the true/false is a part of `strstr()` - meaning "before needle"

Comment: Sorry, edited my post it should be right now